# Generic methods returning simple types

Tags: c#, generics

Ok,
I've got a bit of code that I don't like very much. Given that I didn't write it and merely inherited it, it occurs to me that I could clean it up a little. Basically, we have an object for settings that is persisted with NHibernate. I won't bore you with the implementation details except to say that it contains a dictionary that has the actual values we're keeping in the database.

Our typical property implementation looks like this:

```
public string MyDumbProperty
{
get { return GetStringValue("MyDumbProperty", string.Empty); }
set { SetValue("MyDumbProperty", value);}
}
```

Now, it's probably obvious from the implementation above that we have separate Getxxxx methods for each of the types we return (strings, ints, longs, floats, etc.), with the second parameter being a default value. What I want is to be able to do something like the following:

```
public string MyDumbProperty
{
get { return GetValue("MyDumbProperty", string.Empty); }
set { SetValue("MyDumbProperty", value);}
}
```

I have a couple of reasons for wanting to do this. The big one is that I have a personal dislike of methods named based on what types of parameters they take. The second is that I'd like to make a resharper template for this crap. Then I could just fill in the name of the property and the type and be done (presuming that resharper could give a reasonable default value for the type).

I had thought of making a generic method GetValue that returned a T, but I'm not sure how I need to set up the generic constraints so this is doable. The types being returned from this will all be basic types (strings, ints, etc). There are a couple that return arrays, but I could always do something different on those. This isn't a high priority issue, by any means, but it annoys me every time I see it. I just think there should be a better way to do this.

I suppose a first step would be to just rename the various methods. Since they vary on what type is being passed for the default in the second parameter, I could at least coerce them to the same name. But I could I do better than that? It would be great if I could get rid of the multiple bits of repetitive code in each method that are only different in terms of the datatype being used (TryParse in all the numeric ones).

Comment: Have you looked at how DependancyProperty is deployed?  You basically have the model there for a DependancyProperty!

Comment: This all really depends on what your `GetValue` method does. Generics would easily make this would, and the type could be inferred by the second parameter.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what type do you make your dictionary? If it stores all different types of values is it just a Dictionary<string, object> anyway that would come with all the boxing/unboxing that people are trying to avoid?

Comment: Er, em, "easily make this work"

Comment: The dictionary in question is <string, string>. We parse the strings to get our object values out. All the GetValue does is pull the value, parse it if it exists and returns the default if it doesn't. It just seems wasteful to have so many overloads when the logic is so similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `default(T)` to get the default value of a type.

```
public T Get<T>(string propertyName)
{
    object obj;
    if (propertyBag.TryGetValue(propertyName, out obj)) {
        return (T)obj;
    }
    if(typeof(T) == typeof(string)) {
        return String.Empty;
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

As an alternative you could have two overloads, one accepting an explicit default value.

```
public T Get<T>(string propertyName)
{
    return Get<T>(propertyName, default(T));
}

public T Get<T>(string propertyName, T defaultValue)
{
    object obj;
    if (propertyBag.TryGetValue(propertyName, out obj)) {
        return (T)obj;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but he cannot use a generic constraint to limit what T can be.  A developer could use it as `Get<SomeUnsupportedType>` and it would fail at runtime.

Comment: Also, default<string> is null, where he seems to want the default for string to be string.Empty.

Comment: Why should it fail at runtime? Any type should work as long as you retrieve the same type that you stored before. He could write `if(typeof(T) == typeof(string)) return String.Empty; return default(T);` is this is really an issue.

Comment: @Mou: Specify the desired type: `string s = obj.Get<string>("propName"); int i = obj.Get<int>("propName2");`

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be able to get away with a generic method if the guts of it aren't too complicated. For example, maybe something like this:

```
public T GetValue<T>(string name, T ifNull) where T : IConvertible
{
    string value = GetProperty(name);
    if (value == null)
        return ifNull;
    try
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
    catch
    {
        return ifNull;
    }
}
```

For arrays, you might need a `GetArrayValue` function that does something different.

Comment: you show show how to call this function `GetValue<T>`

Answer (score 1):

The great thing about .net generics is that they can be implicitly used when it is clear which parameters they represent. Not sure about the grammar on that sentence, but a lot surer of that it's possible based on using it a lot..

e.g. for the GetValue:

```
 public T GetValue<T>(string PropertyName, T DefaultValue)
 {

 }

 .... return GetValue("Prop1", 4); //T = int
 .....return GetValue("Prop2", string.Empty) //T= string
 //for nullable times, you can always include the generic parameter
 GetValue<int[]>("Prop3",null);
 //or by 'strongly typing' the null value:
 GetValue("Prop3", (int[])null); //for set this isn't a problem, since 'value' already is strongly typed
```

the same for setting

```
public void SetValue<T>(string PropertyName, T Value)
{
}
```

Comment: What will `GetValue<T>` do if I invoke `GetValue<SomeUnsupportedType>`?  I believe the OP wants to constrain T to a range of primitive types.

Comment: Does he? I could be mistaken, but I thought he only wanted a cleaner syntax on how the properties are called. Ah well, seeing all the other answers it could be I'm misreading the question.

Comment: Well, upon some reflection (mental reflection, not System.Reflection), it occurs to me that I'm not constrained to using primitive types in this, as I could always serialize to JSON and stuff things in there. At the moment, that hasn't happened, but I "could" do it. I probably shouldn't though.
That said, I could use my JSON serializer to pull any arbitrary type out (including primitives, I think). That might really simplify things, as it could all be in one place without having to duplicate code. Hmm, I'll have to test this and see if it's going to hurt me on performance.

Comment: This will work, except if the default value is ambiguous (e.g. `null`), then you'll have to cast it so that the type inference works